# how to access multiple select array data in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, multiple-select

I have a multiple select box and I want to access the selected data in javascript.
Here is the code:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" id="multisel">
  <select name="a[]" id="a" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option value="Pedro">1</option>
    <option value="Alexis">2</option>
    <option value="Messi">3</option>
    <option value="Villa">4</option>
    <option value="Andres">5</option>
    <option value="Sergio">6</option>
    <option value="Xavi">7</option>
  </select>

  <button id="btn1" onclick="ajaxmultiselect()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

  <p id="status"></p>
</form>
```

Here is the code I have tried so far :

```
<script>    
function ajaxmultiselect(){
  var input  = [];
  input = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var status = _("status");
  if(input == ""){
    status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
  }else {
    status.innerHTML = input;
  }
}
</script>
```

When I run the code it only gives the first value.
I tried to access the values in php and it works fine, it passes the value as an array in php. Why isn't it doing the same with javascript?

I also tried to run a loop for the length of the value but that calculates the length of the first selection only.
I want to display all the values that will be selected.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A better way of accessing that value is `document.forms[0].a.value`. `document.forms[0]` is the first form and `form.a` is the element with ID 'a' in that form.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
function getSelectedOptions(element) {
    // validate element
    if(!element || !element.options)
        return []; //or null?

    // return HTML5 implementation of selectedOptions instead.
    if (element.selectedOptions)
        return element.selectedOptions;

    // you are here because your browser doesn't have the HTML5 selectedOptions
    var opts = element.options;
    var selectedOptions = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
         if(opts[i].selected) {
             selectedOptions.push(opts[i]);
         }
    }
    return selectedOptions;
}
```

and then change your `ajaxmultiselect()` so you call it like this:

```
input = getSelectedOptions(document.getElementById("a"));
```

You will have to iterate for the values tho.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to get multiple selected items you could try something like the following:

```
function GetSelectedItems() {
            var select = document.forms[0].a;
            var selectedList = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
                if (select.options[i].selected) {
                    selectedList.push(select.options[i].value);
                }
            }

            alert(Array.join(selectedList, ","));
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I did manage to display a csv of the selected options  (with your code help ). Now how can I check if it is behaving as an array after joining ?? Is there any way to display it, I want to do that because I am passing the end result in an AJAX request to php, but the response is blank.

Comment: So instead of Array.join you could just return the array object. The Array.join converts it to a string.  In my example just return selectedList in place of the alert.

Comment: When I display the selectedList as it is from your example, without using AJAX, it displays a csv. But when I send the same selectedList through ajax the response text is blank. Also, php recognises the selectedList as an array, since I dont get any errors from the foreach loop that I am using in the code. When I send the alert, php doesnt take it as an array.

Comment: I am sorry.. My bad... php doesnt recognize selectedList as an array. I have to explode it to make an array which is still blank.

Comment: If you are wanting to pass this off to the server side on a post back, you will just read it in from the name on your control.  I am not 100% sure, but I don't know if you can have [] in your control name.  I believe through UrlEncoding the [] will be replaced and possibly change the name of the control data in the querystring or form collection.  I do not write PHP, so I am not in the know there.  If you are just validating then you can check to see the length of the array and perform a task based on the length.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('a').options //All Options
```

This will give you an array of options that you can iterate through.

Comment: This doesn't work on Firefox tho, maybe it doesn't work in IE either, look at this page to see that Mozilla hasn't implemented it yet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement

Answer (score 0):

For a given `<select>` element, all of the selected options are in the `selectedOptions` property. The `selectedIndex` property has the index of the first selected option, or `-1` if there is no selection. Each of the options are the DOM object for that element, so their value is in the `value` property. So:

```
function ajaxmultiselect(){
  var input  = [];
  var select = document.forms[0].a;
  var status = _("status");
  var options = select.selectedOptions;
  if(select.selectedIndex == -1){
    // no selection
    status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
  }else {
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length)
      input.push(options[i].value);
    status.innerHTML = input.join(", ");
  }
}
```

From there you should be able to derive whatever you want.

Comment: I believe selectedOptions is a thingy only from WebKit (Chrome and Opera), so FF doesn't work with this, and maybe IE doesn't work either. Look at this page, it shows Mozilla hasn't implemented it yet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement;

Comment: I actually noticed because I'm using FF atm, if I was using Chrome, I would have answered the same as you xD

Comment: My life (as a hobby web designer) would be so much simpler if every rendering engine was interchangeable (with WebKit). WebKit is awesome. FYI, Safari is also WebKit.

Comment: forget about webkit, Blink is the new tomorrow