# Check if two options have been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know if two options from a select dropdown list have been chosen so I can take the text and make a button that has that text inside of it show up. Right now the button shows with some text before the options have been clicked but doesn't show up again if closed and options have been chosen.

If someone has answered this question please let me know I couldn't find anything to help me.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var valueFrom = $('#revenueFrom option:selected').text();
  var valueTo = $('#revenueTo option:selected').text();

  if ($('#revenueFrom option').data('clicked', true) && $('#revenueTo option').data('clicked', true)) {
    $('#annual-revenue-button').text("");
    $('#annual-revenue-button').append(valueFrom + "To:" + valueTo + "&ensp;" + "&times;");
    $('#annual-revenue-button').show('fast');
  };

});

$('.search-popup').click(function () {
  $(this).hide('fast');
});
```

```css
button{
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display:none;
}
button:hover{
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="search-popup btn" id="annual-revenue-button" type="button"></button>


<form class="form-inline revenue">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Annual Revenue</label>
    <select name="revenueFrom" class="form-control" id="revenueFrom">
      <option value="" selected disabled>From:</option>
      <option value="0">$0</option>
      <option value="1">$500,000</option>
      <option value="2">$1 Million</option>
      <option value="3">$2.5 Million</option>
      <option value="4">$5 Million</option>
    </select>
    <select name="revenueTo" class="form-control to" id="revenueTo">
      <option value="" selected disabled>To:</option>
      <option value="0">$0</option>
      <option value="1">$500,000</option>
      <option value="2">$1 Million</option>
      <option value="3">$2.5 Million</option>
      <option value="4">$5 Million</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a `.change()` event listener on the `select` elements.
When one of them has been changed, check the values of those `select` elements are not empty, and then show your button.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#revenueFrom, #revenueTo').change(function(){
    if ($('#revenueFrom').val() && $('#revenueTo').val()) {
      var valueFrom = $('#revenueFrom option:selected').text();
      var valueTo = $('#revenueTo option:selected').text();

      $('#annual-revenue-button').html("From: " + valueFrom + " To: " + valueTo + "&ensp;&times;").show('fast');
    };
  });

});

$('.search-popup').click(function () {
  $(this).hide('fast');
});
```

```css
button{
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display:none;
}
button:hover{
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="search-popup btn" id="annual-revenue-button" type="button"></button>


<form class="form-inline revenue">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Annual Revenue</label>
    <select name="revenueFrom" class="form-control" id="revenueFrom">
      <option value="" selected disabled>From:</option>
      <option value="0">$0</option>
      <option value="1">$500,000</option>
      <option value="2">$1 Million</option>
      <option value="3">$2.5 Million</option>
      <option value="4">$5 Million</option>
    </select>
    <select name="revenueTo" class="form-control to" id="revenueTo">
      <option value="" selected disabled>To:</option>
      <option value="0">$0</option>
      <option value="1">$500,000</option>
      <option value="2">$1 Million</option>
      <option value="3">$2.5 Million</option>
      <option value="4">$5 Million</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I had no idea about the .change event handler! It works perfectly now and I really really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Multiple` and add `[]` after `name=revenueFrom` So an array with all of the elements is being passed on form submission.

This post may also be of use to you [how to access multiple select array data in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448587/how-to-access-multiple-select-array-data-in-javascript)

Note this function:

```
function getSelectedOptions(element) {
    // validate element
    if(!element || !element.options)
        return []; //or null?

    // return HTML5 implementation of selectedOptions instead.
    if (element.selectedOptions)
        return element.selectedOptions;

    // you are here because your browser doesn't have the HTML5 selectedOptions
    var opts = element.options;
    var selectedOptions = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
         if(opts[i].selected) {
             selectedOptions.push(opts[i]);
         }
    }
    return selectedOptions;
}
```

It would also be possible to make an event listener that looks for change on the select and appends a new element somewhere else with the selected data if that's what you needed, feel free to update your question if you need a more specific answer.